# String to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, date-format

I saved a datetime.datetime.now() as a string.
Now I have a string value, i.e.

```
2010-10-08 14:26:01.220000
```

How can I convert this string to

```
Oct 8th 2010
```

?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('2010-10-08 14:26:01.220000'[:-7], 
                '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%b %d %Y')
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create an intermediate string.
You can go directly from a `datetime` to a string with [**`strftime()`**](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime):

```
>>> datetime.now().strftime('%b %d %Y')
'Oct 08 2010'
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no one-liner way, because of your apparent requirement of the grammatical ordinal.

It appears you're using a 2.6 release of Python, or perhaps later.  In such a case,

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("2010-10-08 14:26:01.220000", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").strftime("%b %d %Y")
```

comes close, yielding

```
Oct 08 2010
```

To insist on '8th' rather than '08' involves calculating the **%b** and **%Y** parts as above, and writing a decimal-to-ordinal function to intercalate between them.